# broom::tidy() & tbl_regression() throws Error in profile.glm(object, which = parm, alpha = (1 - level)/4, trace = trace)

Tags: r, broom, gtsummary

I ran a logistic regression as follows, and from the model object I could get coefficients by directly running the model object or via summary. However, trying to do the same with tbl_regression() function throws the error. I am not sure how to fix this, any help would be appreciated.

```r
library(gtsummary)
  load("C:/Users/Public/Documents/mio_ivor1_imp.RDA")
  logist_30dmort_adj <- glm(mortality_30day ~ approach_012 + age + female1 + asa_score + neoadjuvant_analys + cstage_analys + ope_yr_analys + hospital_vol_analys, mio_ivor1_imp, family = binomial)

summary(logist_30dmort_adj)
#> 
#> Call:
#> glm(formula = mortality_30day ~ approach_012 + age + female1 + 
#>     asa_score + neoadjuvant_analys + cstage_analys + ope_yr_analys + 
#>     hospital_vol_analys, family = binomial, data = mio_ivor1_imp)
#> 
#> Deviance Residuals: 
#>      Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
#> -1.15235  -0.19589  -0.11796  -0.06798   3.09348  
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>                         Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
#> (Intercept)            -11.70437  521.81937  -0.022  0.98211   
#> approach_0121           -0.30851    0.68431  -0.451  0.65211   
#> approach_0122           -0.67283    0.86303  -0.780  0.43562   
#> age                      0.08611    0.03185   2.703  0.00686 **
#> female11                -0.94071    0.75947  -1.239  0.21548   
#> asa_score.L              1.99191    0.92262   2.159  0.03085 * 
#> asa_score.Q             -0.18094    0.71959  -0.251  0.80146   
#> asa_score.C             -0.42744    0.44134  -0.969  0.33279   
#> neoadjuvant_analys1      0.40230    0.72689   0.553  0.57995   
#> neoadjuvant_analys2      0.43587    0.58262   0.748  0.45438   
#> cstage_analys.L          0.66557    0.65909   1.010  0.31258   
#> cstage_analys.Q          0.18363    0.52716   0.348  0.72758   
#> cstage_analys.C          0.33085    0.39319   0.841  0.40010   
#> ope_yr_analys.L         -5.23155 3119.87967  -0.002  0.99866   
#> ope_yr_analys.Q         -2.24941 3500.05087  -0.001  0.99949   
#> ope_yr_analys.C         -8.99084 3320.60681  -0.003  0.99784   
#> ope_yr_analys^4        -10.49249 2820.35758  -0.004  0.99703   
#> ope_yr_analys^5         -2.78503 2138.26572  -0.001  0.99896   
#> ope_yr_analys^6          0.89335 1493.93098   0.001  0.99952   
#> ope_yr_analys^7         -4.02858  926.49686  -0.004  0.99653   
#> ope_yr_analys^8         -5.46683  570.70847  -0.010  0.99236   
#> ope_yr_analys^9          3.70191  342.06586   0.011  0.99137   
#> ope_yr_analys^10         3.12888  263.79515   0.012  0.99054   
#> ope_yr_analys^11        -5.76733  322.81793  -0.018  0.98575   
#> ope_yr_analys^12        -3.05926  201.09534  -0.015  0.98786   
#> ope_yr_analys^13         7.58505  522.03343   0.015  0.98841   
#> hospital_vol_analys.L   -0.65262    0.39766  -1.641  0.10077   
#> hospital_vol_analys.Q    0.25345    0.42534   0.596  0.55126   
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)
#> 
#>     Null deviance: 265.43  on 1367  degrees of freedom
#> Residual deviance: 213.11  on 1340  degrees of freedom
#>   (36 observations deleted due to missingness)
#> AIC: 269.11
#> 
#> Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 18
       tbl_regression(logist_30dmort_adj, exponentiate = TRUE)
#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
#> Warning: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
#> Warning: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
#> Warning: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
#> Warning: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
#> Warning: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
#> Warning: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
#> Warning: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
#> Warning: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
#> Warning: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
#> Warning: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
#> Warning: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
#> Warning: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
#> Warning: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
#> Warning: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
#> Warning: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
#> Warning: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
#> Warning: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
#> Warning: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
#> Warning: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
#> Warning: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
#> Warning: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
#> Warning: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
#> Warning: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
#> Warning: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
#> Warning: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
#> Warning: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
#> Warning: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred

#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
#> Warning: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
#> Warning: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
#> Warning: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge
#> Warning: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred
#> x There was an error calling `tidy_fun()`. Most likely, this is because
#>   the function supplied in `tidy_fun=` was misspelled, does not exist,
#>   is not compatible with your object, or was missing necessary arguments (e.g.
#>   `conf.level=` or `conf.int=`). See error message below.
#> Error: Error in profile.glm(object, which = parm, alpha = (1 - level)/4, trace = trace): profiling has found a better solution, so original fit had not converged
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example

Comment: I don't know how to provide a reproducible example to demonstrate the error, but I have tried as best as I can to show what I see including showing the "Show Traceback".
 I am very happy to provide more info if it is more informative, so please ask

Comment: how can I go about reproducing the error? am open to suggestions

Comment: https://reprex.tidyverse.org/ Review this, and please update the post with a reprex.

Comment: This is the closest I have come across to the error, but it is different as in this case, the function works: https://www.biostars.org/p/373507/

Comment: thanks for the repex, but as I understand the issue, my problem is finding data that I can use to demonstrate the error - this is what I mean by saying I don't know how to provide a reproducible error

Comment: @DanielD.Sjoberg I have now used repex.

Comment: The error at the end indicates that the error was while running the function in the `tidy_fun=` argument. For `glm()` this is `broom::tidy()`. If the tidying function cannot run, then `tbl_regression()` cannot either. Perhaps re-tag this post about the broom package, and see if there is anyone who can help diagnose the issue?